# Calling a Java class with PHP's exec function

Tags: java, php

I need to split a text into sentences, and I am trying to use Stanford Core NLP. I have downloaded the library. Since its a Java library I am using PHP's exec command (please see below) to call it. My PHP script works well and I can parse a text into sentences. Currently, the script needs an input file to be parsed. My question is if I can use a PHP string variable instead of input .txt file. It will be very convenient for me since I will be using mysql db to retrieve text/string. If it is not possible, then I would need to create a corresponding text file for the command line input. Any feedback you provide will greatly be appreciated.

Here is my small PHP script

```
$text = "Maria and Ted Bobola grow sweet corn. But with little corn to harvest because of a plant-withering drought, the Bobolas were forced to buy corn from Georgia to supply their produce and flower shop just outside Dover. And most years, the strawberry picking season runs three to five weeks, but not this year, store manager Dee Chambers said. ``It was so hot and dry that even though we irrigated, we had only two weeks in the season,'' she said. They did not recoup $70,000 they paid for strawberry plants last year in this year's harvest."; 

$parser = "stanford-corenlp-3.5.0.jar";
$class = "edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor"; 
$input = "sample.txt"; 
$output = "output.txt";  
if (exec( "java -cp $parser -Xmx2g $class -file $input", $result))
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "failure"; 
    }

// Optional
echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true);
```

What I am trying to do here is replacing $input (i.e. txt file) with $text (i.e. a php variable).

Comment: If you give "-" as the filename, many programs treat this as meaning "read from standard input". If this does - and it may not - then you could pipe it into the command or use a heredoc. Does it really matter though? You can get a temporary file with tempnam, write it with file_put_contents, and delete it again with unlink, in only two or three lines. And the text doesn't then need escaping (in case it contains quotes or whatever) to get it into the shell as it would if it were passed from the command line itself.